# Erro ao restaurar backup mysql

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, backup

Boa tarde Pessoal.

Estou com um problema relacionado ao backup e restauração dos dados de um banco MySQL.
Gerei um backup dos dados utilizando o mysqldump para formatar o pc e instalar um novo sistema operacional.

Acontece que agora estou tentando restaurar os dados, porém, não estou conseguindo. Estou usando o console do MySQL com o comando {`source arquivo.sql`}, mas não restaura. Nem erro ele dá.

O que me chama a atenção é que o arquivo tem dados (o tamanho do arquivo é de 200MB), mas ao abri-lo pelo bloco de notas, por exemplo, não aparece nada. É como se o arquivo tivesse apenas espaços em branco. Consigo até selecionar os espaços em branco.

Alguém já passou por algo assim?

Não sei se ficou claro a minha explicação..